# Should I choose 32-bit or 64-bit to install Ubuntu on a Macbook Pro Laptop?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, architecture

Which installation do I choose for Apple Macbook Pro Laptop, 32-bit or 64-bit?

My computer specs:
15-inch - Mid/Late 2007 - 2.4/2.2GHz

Comment: As your Macbook Pro is over 5 years old I would suggest 32 bit, although if you are happy to try it, try the 64 bit first just for fun. I will not harm the computer and it may work.

Comment: @Coxime What is your output for `uname -a`?

Comment: Also, you should mention the OS that your are running, not only the model of your computer.

Comment: Ah, you neglect to mention the essential criterion for choosing 64-bit over 32-bit: your system's installed memory. 64-bit will support more than 4GB RAM, *but* will be slower if you have little RAM. So I would suggest sticking with 32-bit if your system has less than 4 GB RAM, and use 64-bit if you have more than 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Ubuntu, 13.04, has a mac version of the installation media. It is 64-bit, and should work better than just a standard version of Ubuntu. [Click here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/) to see the list of downloads for Ubuntu 13.04. Download the one that says amd64+mac.

There are several guides I have read that suggest using rEFIt or rEFInd to manage the EFI booting on Macbooks, however, I was successful with just using the 13.04 amd64+mac version without any other software or configuration needed.